# Javascript: Calling a function's function in a namespace

Tags: javascript, function, constructor, namespaces, prototype

file1.js

---

```
var Namespace = {};

Namespace.addNewFunc = function(x,y,z) {

  function callMe() {
    // Call this function
  }

}
```

file2.js

---

Namespace.addNewFunc.callMe() ??

Not exactly sure how to reach the contents of callMe() using the namespace.

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense. `callMe` only exists when `addNewFunc` is called and then a) no other code can  be executed in parallel and b) the function would not be accessible from the outside anyway. Why did you make `addNewFunc` a function and declared `callMe` inside of it if you want to access `callMe` statically outside of `callMe`?

Comment: I see what you mean now, I was mainly wondering if it were possible to access it this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can't acces variables (function are also variables) in the scope of another function (variables declared with `var` or `function`) are scoped.

You can do

```
NameSpace.callMe = function(){}
```

or

```
NameSpace.addNewFunc.callMe = function(){}
```